# Importing mutiple Excel(xlsx) files into SAS

Tags: import, macros, sas, proc

I have around 70 excel documents in a library and I would like to import all of them into the SAS environment. So, I am wondering is there any macro to do this?

Comment: Hello. You can write universal code to import one file into lib, and launch it to all files in dir. Can you?

Comment: This is in testing https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Import_all_files_one_type

Comment: Also, check SAS macro appendix in SAS 9.4 documentation.

Comment: Thank You @ Reeza

Answer (score 0):

Your favorite search engine will find many solutions, such as this one: http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Streamlining_Data-Driven_SAS_With_The_%25FOR_Macro